# Swift var score does not increase

Tags: swift, var

```
var players : [Player]?
var currentplayerIndex = 0
var currentQuestion : QuestionObject!
var questions = Questions()
var score = 0
var currentQuestionPos = 0


func updateUi() {
    if let score = players?[currentplayerIndex].score {
        playerPoints.text = "Points: \(score)"
    }
}

 func loadnextQuestion () {
        if(currentQuestionPos < questions.questions.count) {
        currentQuestionPos += 1

        if currentplayerIndex < players!.count - 1 {
            currentplayerIndex += 1
        } else {
            currentplayerIndex = 0
        }
            playerTurn.text = (players?[currentplayerIndex].name)
            currentQuestion = questions.questions[currentQuestionPos]
            questionText.text = currentQuestion.question
    }
}


@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let i = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    if(currentQuestion.answer == i) {
        players?[currentplayerIndex].score += 1
        loadnextQuestion()
        updateUi()
    } else {
        updateUi()
        loadnextQuestion()
    }
}
```

}

My score displays only 0 all the time.
Does not increase when the answer is right.
All the added players get 1 question each but the sore is still 0 for all the players.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you are doing this series of things when the answer is correct:

```
players?[currentplayerIndex].score += 1
loadnextQuestion()
updateUi()
```

The player's score is *indeed* incremented. But notice that the next thing you do is `loadnextQuestion()`, which increments `currentplayerIndex`. This causes `updateUi` to update the label's text to the score of the *next* player, not of the player that just answered the question correctly.

One way to fix this is to swap the last two lines:

```
players?[currentplayerIndex].score += 1
updateUi()
loadnextQuestion()
```

Notice that this is the same order as in the `else` branch, which you wrote correctly.

This causes the label to always display the score of the last player, which might not be desirable. Assuming there's not like 100 players or something crazy like that, I think it would be a much better UX if you display all the player's scores:

```
func updateUi() {
    if let scores = players?.map({ "\($0.score)" }) {
        playerPoints.text = "Points: \(scores.joined(separator: ", "))"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the button action work

```
@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let i = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    if(currentQuestion.answer == i) {
        players?[currentplayerIndex].score += 1
        updateUi()
        loadnextQuestion()
    } else {
        updateUi()
        loadnextQuestion()
    }
}
```